# Order Post by Episodes number (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Some of my post are out of order (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OENv.jpg) So I tried adding this code in the Theme Functions to have it order by episodes with no luck.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_sort_order'); 

    function my_change_sort_order($query)
    {
        if(is_archive()):

            //If you wanted it for the archive of a custom post type use: is_post_type_archive( $post_type )
           //Set the order ASC or DESC
           $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );

           //Set the orderby
           $query->set( 'orderby', 'SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, "Episode ", 1) ASC, CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, "Episode ", -1) AS SIGNED)' );

        endif;    
    };
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If I were you, I'd make the episode number a piece of meta data and then orderby the meta value.

Comment: If you can't add the episode as metadata as Aibrean suggested, you could sort the posts themselves after you get them - instead of displaying them in the loop, get them as an array and do the sort there.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_sort_order'); 

    function my_change_sort_order($query)
    {
        if(is_archive()):

            $query->set('orderby', array('date' => 'DESC', 'title'=> 'DESC'));

        endif;    
    };
```